# Почему не работает запрос к базе данных?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Понадобилось добавить данные в конкретную ячейку таблицы в результате чего я нагуглил такой пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовав у себя в командной строке что то подобное(правда не совсем в похожей ситуации) - у меня ничего не вышло:


[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
Почему не заработала команда и какая команда необходима что бы решить поставленную задачу?
(вставить значение в отсутствующее поле заголовка "Страна_Поставщика")

Comment: *какая команда необходима что бы решить поставленную задачу?* А где постановка задачи-то? её нет. Вы уж озаботьтесь... вместо картинок... которые, кстати, надо бы заменить на цитаты текстом. И - в таблице нет ячеек (это не Эксель), там есть записи и есть поля (как в структуре, т.е. вообще, так и конкретные поля конкретных уже существующих записей).

Comment: >> А где постановка задачи-то?
читайте внимательнее.

Comment: *вставить значение в отсутствующее поле заголовка "Страна_Поставщика"* Вам нужно обновление существующей записи, а не вставка новой. Это делается запросом UPDATE. `UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = value WHERE COALESCE(fieldname, '') = '';`.

Comment: уже так пробовал ранее и у меня ничего не работало:
http://joxi.ru/V2V64PLCxXlRW2
Почему это происходит?

Comment: Вы что, не умеете текст копипастить? А по показанной проблеме - смотрите, что это за констрейнт, что именно и как он ограничивает.

Comment: Попробуйте просто колонку указать в кавычках
INSERT INTO perfect_goods('Страна_Поставщика') VALUES ('Китай');

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'Страна_Поставщика'"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO perfect_goods('Страна_Поставщика') VALUES ('Кита...

Comment: Только кавычки двойные двойные, вот такие "

Comment: ERROR:  column "Китай" does not exist
LINE 1: ...RT INTO perfect_goods("Страна_Поставщика") VALUES ("Китай");